# Check content of array before acting

Tags: java

The purpose of this program is to build a 10x10 array grid made out of periods (.), allow the user to designate a starting point, and then the program will randomly choose numbers which are assigned to directions for the 'walker' to go. Each time it moves it marks its spot with the next letter in the alphabet (the starting point is marked by A). If the walker crosses out of the bounds of the array (AKA > 10 or < 0) it will say "you were arrested" and if the variable alpha == 'Z' it way say "You made it home".

The only thing I have left to do is make it so that if the walker tries to go back to a spot it has already been to, it will skip to the next space until it reaches a space it hasn't been.

```
package walktester;

import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class DrunkWalker {
    private char[][] walkgrid = new char[10][10];
    private static int randNSEW;
    private int randomnum;
    private int startrow;
    private int startcol;
    private char alpha = 'A';
    private int nextrow;
    private int nextcol;

    public DrunkWalker(int r, int c) {
        startrow = r;
        startcol = c;
        nextrow = startrow;
        nextcol = startcol;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                walkgrid[i][j] = '.';
        }
        walkgrid[r][c] = alpha++;
    }

    public static void getRand(){
        int x100 = 0;
        double randomNum = 0.0;
        randomNum = Math.random();
        x100 = (int) (randomNum * 100);
        randNSEW = x100 % 4;
    }

    public int getNextRow(){
        return nextrow;
    }

    public int getNextCol(){
        return nextcol;
    }

    public boolean processing(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i ++){
        getRand();
        if(randNSEW == 0){
            nextcol--;
        }
        if(randNSEW == 1){
            nextrow++;
        }
        if(randNSEW == 2){
            nextcol++;
        }
        if(randNSEW == 3){
            nextrow--;
        }

        if(nextrow < 0 || nextrow >= 10 || nextcol < 0 || nextcol >= 10) {
            return false;
        }

        walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] = alpha++;
    }
    return true;
}



    public char[][] DisplayGrid() {
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            System.out.print(walkgrid[x][y] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return walkgrid;
}
}

public class WalkTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inpr = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inpc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inpchoice = new Scanner(System.in);

        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;
        char choice = 'y';

        while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y') {
            System.out.println("Please enter x coordinate between 1 and 10.");
            r = inpr.nextInt();
            r = r - 1;

            System.out.println("Please enter y coordinate between 1 and 10");
            c = inpr.nextInt();
            c = c - 1;

            if(r < 0 || r > 9 || c < 0 || c > 9){
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Restart? y/n");
                choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
                if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
                    continue;
                }
                else if(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'){
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Restart? y/n");
                    choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
                }
            }
            DrunkWalker drunkwalker = new DrunkWalker(r, c);
            boolean walkerSucceeded = drunkwalker.processing();
            drunkwalker.DisplayGrid();
            if(walkerSucceeded) {
                System.out.println("You made it home");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You were arrested");
            }

            System.out.println("Restart? y/n");
            choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
            if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
                continue;
            }
            else if(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'){
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Restart? y/n");
                choice = inpchoice.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By "*skip to the next space until it reaches a space*" I assume you mean they continue on in the same direction.

So, just before you do:

```
walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] = alpha++;
```

you need to check:

```
if (walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] == '.')
```

so something along these lines:

```
    ...
    do {
        if (randNSEW == 0) nextcol--;
        if (randNSEW == 1) nextrow++;
        if (randNSEW == 2) nextcol++;
        if (randNSEW == 3) nextrow--;

        if ((nextrow < 0) || (nextrow >= 10) || (nextcol < 0) || (nextcol >= 10)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] == '.') continue;  /* try next */
        walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] = alpha++;
    } while (false);
```

Or we could rewrite those last three lines as:

```
    } while (walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] == '.');
    walkgrid[nextrow][nextcol] = alpha++;
```